# Use wordpress search to display results within a post

Tags: search

I want to have to display related post within a post based on the post title. So for example I have a post named "France gas prices". First it displays all the post info but then under the post I want to have search results displayed using the "france gas prices" value. Now I could use this. (example search on specific meta data but i would be happy if it just searched post title)

```
<?php $title = get_the_title() ?>
<?php query_posts('meta_key=review_type&meta_value=$title');  ?> 
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?> 
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

And then display the info from the found posts as I want but the problem is then I will only find exact matches. It wont find gas prices france or any other result like wordpress build in search would give.

How can I access the build in wordpress search give it a term dynamicly based on post title and then choose what I display from the found posts and how I display the info?

---> in other words how do you the build in wordpress functionality to fill a wp_query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`WP_Query` accepts a search parameter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Search_Parameter), 's'. Hence, you can just do this:

```
<?php $related_posts = new WP_Query( 's=' . the_title_attribute( '', '', 0 ) );

if( $related_posts->have_posts() ) : while( $related_posts->have_posts() ) : $related_posts->the_post();

    // STUFF

endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

While we're here, note the use of `WP_Query` which is more appropriate for a secondary loop. You can also take a look at the link above if you want to add additional paramemters to restrict by `post_type` or taxonomy or anything else.